# Gradient Color For Line Chart In ng2-charts

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I am trying to apply gradient color for line chart in [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/). But I am getting error

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`

**Code**

```
<canvas #myCanvas [colors]="lineChartColors" ...
export class Demo {
  @ViewChild("myCanvas") canvas: ElementRef;
  lineChartColors;

// in ngOnInit
let gradient = this.canvas.nativeElement.getContext('2d').createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'green');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
this.lineChartColors = [
  {
    backgroundColor: gradient
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML doesn't completely exist in the `ngOnInit` hook.
you should do it inside `ngAfterViewInit()` function.
The definition for this hook is

> ngAfterViewInit() 
>   Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views / the view that a directive is in.

That means that the HTML is ready here, when you call it in in `ngOnInit()` you actually don't have this element on the page.

[enter here for more info](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: still `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined`